# Optimizing logging in C++ multi-threaded server app for performance and crash-proof data integrity

Tags: c++, multithreading, logging, server, crash

I have a complex server application (Windows/Linux) with several threads, and I need to enable verbose logging occasionally to trace a bug. However, the logging process dramatically slows down the application because, in my current implementation, each log entry is flushed to disk immediately.

I'd like to find a way to get rid of immediate flushing, but I'm uncertain if there are any other options that can guarantee all reported log entries are written to file if the application crashes.

One option I'm considering is running a separate thread for logging. In this approach, other threads would only experience a slowdown while waiting to insert their log entries into a thread-safe queue. However, I'm unsure if it's possible to ensure all entries in the queue are written to disk if the application crashes in the main thread. Can Linux signals or Windows' SetUnhandledExceptionFilter be used in a way that allows such a thread to complete its job?

The other considered opinion is to send log entries over UDP/TCP loopback to another process (e.g., syslog on Linux). However, I'm not sure if this approach would provide any speed gains or if the socket buffers are always sent if the application crashes. Additionally, implementing this solution would definitely increase the complexity of the infrastructure needed for running the application, especially on Windows.

Comment: Your objectives are in conflict.

Comment: First, post your logging code.  Second, what are your performance requirements?

Comment: Also, with respect to *I'm unsure if it's possible to ensure all entries in the queue are written to disk if the application crashes in the main thread*:  if you have an internal queue of log entries stored in memory, you've already abandoned ensuring all log entries are written to disk if the process crashes.

Comment: There is nothing fancy about my current logging code. It just formats message through variadic tempaltes and then invokes fwrite, fflush (and fsync on Linux systems). There is no internal queue of unprocessed log entries. Everything is immediately flushed to disk.

Comment: @zdenek Simple test for Linux: drop the `fsync()`.  If that's not fast enough, then try using `open( ..., O_APPEND ... )` instead of `fopen()`, replace `fwrite()`/`fflush()`/`fsync()` with a simple `write()`.  Fast enough?  If not, profile your code and see if the formatting is slowing things down too much.  That could help on Linux.  In my experience, doing logging like this on Windows is really hard to make performant.  There may be flags you can pass to `CreateFile()` that improve throughput - `FILE_FLAG_OVERLAPPED` might work, but making sure log entries all append might be difficult.

Comment: Instead of attempting to flush all messages to the drive, you could instead enable automatic crash dumps. Ensure that the whole heap is included. I only have experience with them on windows, and there it works quite well. I'd include somewhere in the code a global pointer that points to the messages. Then it is just a matter of entering it in the debugger watch window to get the data. That is, of course, if the call stack itself doesn't reveal the reason for the crash already.

Comment: To clarify what I mean, just let the os create automatic crash dumps and extract the messages that did not get flushed from there.

Comment: @Sedenion Core dumps on Linux (and most other UNIX systems) also include the entire virtual address space of the process that crashed. Digging details out of a core dump is not fun, but - yeah - doable.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

### Requirements

If I understand your requirements correctly, there is an application
with multiple threads logging to a single archive of some type (e.g. a
file). And, all of the information from completed calls to log must be
successfully archived even when the program terminates unexpectedly.

I believe the only way to achieve the strict requirement of capturing
all of the informaiton in an achive is to enforce synchonous
logging. If the writes are not synchronous, there will always be a
window in which some information can be lost. If strictly enforced,
this excludes options such as using a dedicated thread for writing to
the archive.

### Ideas

As far as I know, the best (only?) technique for achieving this goal
with acceptable performance is to use some type of memory-mapping
scheme (like proposed by @N00byEdge). I pulled together some existing
code to construct enough of a prototype of this scheme to do some
measurements.

Another option is to try a high-performance logger like
[spdlog](https://github.com/gabime/spdlog) which is very capable and
performant. I use it for my logging. If you flush on each log message,
however, it will still be two orders of magnitude (100x) slower than a
memory-mapped file.

### Performance Results

Based on your post, I constructed a simple performance test that
measures the time to write 200 Mb of log information to a file using
writers that simply spew information, which I think is the worst case
scenario.

The following plots show the elapsed time to log 200 Mb of information
versus the number of logging threads. I measured three different
prototypes across `Arm64` and `x86`:

- `MemoryFile` with a spin-lock for synchronization
- `MemoryFile` with a mutex for synchronization
- `spdlog` but with 100x less data

[image: x86 results]
[image: arm64 results]

If there is interest, I wouldn't mind working on an open source
implementation of a more generic memory-mapped based `"file"` for use
in situations like this that have strict data guaruntees and
performance requirements.

### Sample Code (`MemoryFile`)

```cpp
#include <atomic>
#include <unistd.h>
#include <sys/mman.h>
#include <fcntl.h>
#include <filesystem>
#include <thread>
#include <vector>
#include <iostream>
#include <chrono>

class SpinLock {
public:
    void lock() {
        while (locked_.test_and_set(std::memory_order_acquire))
            std::this_thread::yield();
    }

    void unlock() {
        locked_.clear(std::memory_order_release);
    }

private:
    std::atomic_flag locked_ = ATOMIC_FLAG_INIT;
};

class SpinLockGuard {
public:
    SpinLockGuard(SpinLock& lock)
        : lock_(lock) {
        lock_.lock();
    }

    ~SpinLockGuard() {
        lock_.unlock();
    }

private:
    SpinLock& lock_;
};

class MemoryFile {
public:
    enum Mode { CREATE, OPEN, CREATE_OR_OPEN };

    struct Header {
        size_t bytes_written{}, bytes_mapped{};
    };

    static constexpr size_t DataOffset = sizeof(Header);

    MemoryFile(const std::string& filename, Mode mode) {
        switch (mode) {
        case CREATE:
            create_chunk(filename);
            break;
        case OPEN:
            open_chunk(filename);
            break;
        case CREATE_OR_OPEN:
            if (std::filesystem::exists(filename)) open_chunk(filename);
            else create_chunk(filename);
            break;
        }
    }

    ~MemoryFile() {
        if (base_)
            munmap(base_, *ptr_bytes_mapped_);
        if (fd_ != -1)
            close(fd_);
    }

    void commit_message(std::string_view msg) {
        // SpinLockGuard guard(lock_);
        std::lock_guard guard(mutex_);
        ensure_room_for_message(msg.size());
        auto nbytes = *ptr_bytes_written_;
        std::copy(msg.begin(), msg.end(), base_ + nbytes);
        nbytes += msg.size();
        *ptr_bytes_written_ = nbytes;
    }

private:
    size_t grow_file(size_t new_size) {
        auto rc = lseek(fd_, new_size - 1, SEEK_SET);
        if (rc + 1 != new_size)
            throw std::runtime_error("error: lseek failed trying to grow file");

        rc = write(fd_, "", 1);
        if (rc != 1)
            throw std::runtime_error("error: write to extend file failed");

        return new_size;
    }

    void map_memory(size_t nbytes) {
        base_ = (char*)mmap(nullptr, nbytes, PROT_READ | PROT_WRITE, MAP_SHARED, fd_, 0);
        if (base_ == nullptr)
            throw std::runtime_error("error: failed to map memory");

        Header *header = (Header*)base_;
        ptr_bytes_written_ = &(header->bytes_written);
        ptr_bytes_mapped_ = &(header->bytes_mapped);
        *ptr_bytes_mapped_ = nbytes;
    }

    void create_chunk(const std::string& filename) {
        namespace fs = std::filesystem;
        if (fs::exists(fs::path(filename)))
            throw std::runtime_error("error: chunk already exists");

        fd_ = open(filename.c_str(), O_CREAT | O_RDWR, 0777);
        if (fd_ == -1)
            throw std::runtime_error("error: failed to create chunk");

        auto nbytes = grow_file(1024 * 1024);
        map_memory(nbytes);
        *ptr_bytes_written_ = sizeof(Header);
    }

    void open_chunk(const std::string& filename) {
        namespace fs = std::filesystem;
        if (not fs::exists(fs::path(filename)))
            throw std::runtime_error("error: chunk does not exist");

        fd_ = open(filename.c_str(), O_RDWR, 0777);
        if (fd_ == -1)
            throw std::runtime_error("error: failed to open chunk");

        auto nbytes = fs::file_size(fs::path(filename));
        map_memory(nbytes);
    }

    void ensure_room_for_message(size_t n) {
        auto nw = *ptr_bytes_written_, nm = *ptr_bytes_mapped_;
        if (nw + n >= nm) {
            munmap(base_, nm);
            base_ = nullptr;

            auto new_size = std::max(2 * nm, nw + n + 1);
            auto nbytes = grow_file(new_size);
            map_memory(nbytes);
        }
    }

    // Pointer to the number of bytes written.
    volatile size_t *ptr_bytes_written_{nullptr};

    // Pointer to the number of bytes in the mapped region.
    volatile size_t *ptr_bytes_mapped_{nullptr};

    // Pointer to the mapped region.
    char *base_{nullptr};

    // File descriptor of the mapped region.
    int fd_{-1};

    // Use simple spin-lock for thread synchronization.
    // SpinLock lock_;

    // Use a mutex for thread synchronization.
    std::mutex mutex_;
};

template<class Clock = std::chrono::high_resolution_clock>
class StopWatch
{
public:
    StopWatch()
        : start_tp_(Clock::now())
        , last_tp_(start_tp_)
    { }

    auto now() const
    {
        std::atomic_thread_fence(std::memory_order_relaxed);
        auto current_tp = Clock::now();
        std::atomic_thread_fence(std::memory_order_relaxed);
        return current_tp;
    }

    auto mark()
    {
        auto current_tp = now();
        auto elapsed = current_tp - last_tp_;
        last_tp_ = current_tp;
        return elapsed;
    }

    template<class Units = typename Clock::duration>
    auto elapsed_duration()
    {
        auto elapsed = mark();
        return std::chrono::duration_cast<Units>(elapsed);
    }

    template<class Units = typename Clock::duration>
    auto elapsed_time()
    {
        auto elapsed = mark();
        return std::chrono::duration_cast<Units>(elapsed).count();
    }

private:
    typename Clock::time_point start_tp_;
    typename Clock::time_point last_tp_;
};

int main(int argc, const char *argv[]) {
    const auto filename = "/tmp/x.out";
    size_t nth = argc >= 2 ? atoi(argv[1]) : 1;
    size_t nmsg = argc >= 3 ? atoi(argv[2]) : 1'000'000;
    size_t msg_per_thread = nmsg / nth;

    std::filesystem::remove(std::filesystem::path(filename));
    MemoryFile log(filename, MemoryFile::CREATE);

    StopWatch timer;
    timer.mark();
    std::vector<std::thread> threads;
    for (auto i = 0; i < nth; ++i)
        threads.emplace_back([&]() {
            for (auto i = 0; i < msg_per_thread; ++i)
                log.commit_message("This is a log message\n");
        });

    for (auto& thread : threads)
        thread.join();

    auto ms = timer.elapsed_duration<std::chrono::milliseconds>().count();
    std::cout << ms << " ms" << std::endl;

    return 0;
}
```

### Sample Code (`spdlog`)

```cpp
#include <iostream>
#include <filesystem>
#include "spdlog/spdlog.h"
#include "spdlog/sinks/basic_file_sink.h"

template<class Clock = std::chrono::high_resolution_clock>
class StopWatch
{
public:
    StopWatch()
        : start_tp_(Clock::now())
        , last_tp_(start_tp_)
    { }

    auto now() const
    {
        std::atomic_thread_fence(std::memory_order_relaxed);
        auto current_tp = Clock::now();
        std::atomic_thread_fence(std::memory_order_relaxed);
        return current_tp;
    }

    auto mark()
    {
        auto current_tp = now();
        auto elapsed = current_tp - last_tp_;
        last_tp_ = current_tp;
        return elapsed;
    }

    template<class Units = typename Clock::duration>
    auto elapsed_duration()
    {
        auto elapsed = mark();
        return std::chrono::duration_cast<Units>(elapsed);
    }

    template<class Units = typename Clock::duration>
    auto elapsed_time()
    {
        auto elapsed = mark();
        return std::chrono::duration_cast<Units>(elapsed).count();
    }

private:
    typename Clock::time_point start_tp_;
    typename Clock::time_point last_tp_;
};

using std::cout, std::endl;

int main(int argc, const char *argv[]) {
    const auto filename = "/tmp/x.out";
    size_t nth = argc >= 2 ? atoi(argv[1]) : 1;
    size_t nmsg = argc >= 3 ? atoi(argv[2]) : 1'000'000;
    size_t msg_per_thread = nmsg / nth;

    std::filesystem::remove(std::filesystem::path(filename));
    auto sink = std::make_shared<spdlog::sinks::basic_file_sink_mt>("/tmp/x.out", true);
    spdlog::logger logger("basic", sink);

    StopWatch timer;
    timer.mark();
    std::vector<std::thread> threads;
    for (auto i = 0; i < nth; ++i)
        threads.emplace_back([&]() {
            for (auto i = 0; i < msg_per_thread; ++i) {
                logger.info("This is a log message\n");
                logger.flush();
            }
        });

    for (auto& thread : threads)
        thread.join();

    auto ms = timer.elapsed_duration<std::chrono::milliseconds>().count();
    std::cout << ms << " ms" << std::endl;

    return 0;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

If you have an upper bound of the amount of data I would do it in the following way:

Create a file and map it into memory with for example `MAP_SHARED` on linux. If your program dies, the changes should be written back to file. All your logging will do to output data will just be a single memcpy. It will be highly performant, keep your data on a crash, but requires you to have an upper bound for the mapping (and resize before mapping) of the file. You could also use the file as a ring buffer and restart at the beginning if you're okay with overwriting old log entries.

Answer (score 0):

One way this can be done is to build a logger similar to existing loggers, which have:

- Severity per message, so some messages are `error`, some are `trace`, and so on
- Configurable flushing per severity, such as "only flush on error", possibly combined with a periodic flush.

If you're logging from multiple threads, you want your logging to be thread-safe anyway, so a thread safe queue and a consumer thread which dequeues and writes this data is a good idea.

Another trick to avoid slowdown of flushes is to write your log files to a ram disk, like `/tmp` on most Linux distros.

The result is a logger that flushes on specific severities. This severity can be adjusted, so, for example, on production-deployed systems you'd only flush on error, but in development environments, you'd flush on debug messages (if that's not too slow).

This works well, especially if you adopt the strategy of logging an error on unexpected values (e.g. you could check your pre- and post-conditions and log an error if they fail).